# When I deploy code through the GoogleAppEngineLauncher, does it upload all files?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

So currently GoogleAppEngineLauncher is pointing to a directory that contains my app.yaml file, along with several other directories - Let's say they are directory A, B and C. If A and B contain python files, template files etc. used by the app, but directory C contains no code whatsoever (it's just a misc directory with random stuff in it), will it still get uploaded when I deploy code?

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheet
  static_dir: stylesheet

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, everything (excepting a few special patterns such as 'dotfiles') gets uploaded as data files, accessible by your app, unless app.yaml specifies that certain files should be served as static files instead.

If you want to exclude files from being uploaded at all, you need to set the skip_files regular expression in your app.yaml, as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Skipping_Files).

Comment: how about subsequent deploys, does it upload all the files again or only those that were changed?

Comment: By default, appcfg will upload all the files (recursively) in the app.yaml-residing directory with each update. You can simulate "incremental deploys" by using [push to deploy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy).

Comment: @Alice Not true - appcfg hashes the files and only uploads files that have changed.

Comment: @Nick Interesting, I didn't know that. Anecdotally, I've experienced a lot of files (~4000) being deployed although only a single file had changed, so I wonder how these hashes are computed and compared to those on the App Engine side? Perhaps there is some OS interference or timestamp differential going on. Is there an easy switch to get the the list of the names of all files being uploaded (instead of just the summary report)?

Comment: @NickJohnson I just deployed twice in a row without touching a single file in between, using --verbose to see the list of files being uploaded. In the second run, the entire directory tree was uploaded again. Do you have a hunch why that could be? I'd really like for my deploys to be fasterrrr :)

Comment: @Alice What were the actual messages? It'll scan them, but shouldn't upload them. Of course, things could have changed since I left the App Engine team. :)

Comment: @NickJohnson - Rereading that answer of yours - it seems it's all of our static files that are causing the slow uploads (we have a lot of them).